# What is this time format, and how do I convert it to an epoch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I have data with timestamps in 2 formats, where `3F536DDA -> 1378397085768000` and `3F52C3C3 -> 1378353476238000`. I can not seem to figure out *what* format `3F536DDA` is in, nor how to convert it to the epoch in question. Any help would be appreciated!

**Update**

I have found this:

*8-digit hexadecimal representation of the time of fix in seconds since January 6, 1980 at time 00:00:00 GMT.*

Which appears to be GPS Time.

I may be missing something from the conversion here, where I just subtract the difference between Jan 6 1980 and Jan 1 1970...

```
time = (1378397085 - 315964800)

console.log '3F536DDA' # What I expected
console.log time.toString(16) # What I get: 3F536D1D
```

Comment: Where are you getting these timestamps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, these just look like hexadecimal numbers, which would be seconds since 1/1/1970 UTC.

```
3F536DDA hex == 1062432218 dec == Mon, 01 Sep 2003 16:03:38 GMT
3F52C3C3 hex == 1062388675 dec == Mon, 01 Sep 2003 03:57:55 GMT
```

The other numbers look like decimal *microseconds* since 1/1/1970 UTC, but they aren't equal to those other numbers:

```
1378397085768000 == Thu, 05 Sep 2013 16:04:45 GMT
1378353476238000 == Thu, 05 Sep 2013 03:57:56 GMT
```

If those aren't the dates you had in mind, then there is some other epoch involved.  For example, if they originated in Microsoft Windows, they will certainly be different.

Where did you get them from?  That knowledge will help in their interpretation.

**UPDATE**

Since you said they are based on Jan 6 1980 epoch, then you can do something like this:

```
var d = new Date(Date.UTC(1980,0,6) + parseInt('3F536DDA', 16) * 1000);
d.toISOString();  // 2013-09-05T16:03:38.000Z
```

Or better yet, using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

```
var m = moment.utc("1980-01-06").add('seconds', parseInt('3F536DDA', 16));
m.toISOString();  // 2013-09-05T16:03:38.000Z
```

Comment: They are coming from an IOT device sending location data (why GPS Time makes sense).

Comment: How does that link help?

Comment: @FrankLoVecchio: They don't both trace back to the exact same epoch, which means something may not be quite right in this rationale. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Mon%2C+01+Sep+2003+16%3A03%3A38+GMT+-+1378397085768000+microseconds and http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Mon%2C+01+Sep+2003+03%3A57%3A55+GMT+-+1378353476238000+microseconds

Comment: Ah, yes I see where you were going with that.

Comment: Moment rocks! That works better then what I was fussing with.

Comment: Glad you like.  Do note that I just showed `.toISOString()` as an example.  You can do lots of other things with a moment, such as format it in any number of ways, or convert it back to local time, or convert to a specific time zone using the moment-timezone addon.

Answer (score 0):

You would think it would just be as easy as diffing between the GPS epoch (midnight January 6, 1980) and the Unix epoch (midnight January 1, 1970).  That answer will get you close but not exact, because GPS time doesn't take into account leap seconds.  There will be drift in the calculation for every leap second added since 1980.

I wrote a helper library that you can use here: https://github.com/davidcalhoun/gps-time.js

If you're interested, the algorithm is essentially this:
1) convert from GPS to Unix epoch
2) for any given date, determine the number of leap seconds that have been added
3) make time adjustment based on how many leap seconds have passed

For this to work with any arbitrary time, including times in the past, this basically requires iterating through lookup table with all the exact times of leap seconds.

Importantly, it also means that to prevent drift, the code needs to be updated every single time a leap second is added in the future.  Luckily it's just as easy as adding the leap second to the lookup table!